# Why does binding trigger a $watch although no data was changed?

Tags: angularjs

I have an entity in the scope that is being edited by the user. Each time it gets modified, I want to trigger some custom validation. So I have:

```
// validate the position if anything has changed
$scope.$watch("entity", function() {
    if ($scope.entity.Id) {
        $scope.validate();
    }
}, true /* watch "by value" (see: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle) */);
```

So far so good. Now, since this is a big entity with quite some fields, not all of the fields participate initially in data-binding. Only portions of the fields are visible to the user by using a tab control. When the user switches tabs, another portion of the entity is shown.

However, when the additional controls get bound to the corresponding fields of the entity, the `$watch` gets triggered even though the binding doesn't change any value on the entity.

Why is this the case and how could I prevent it?

**Note**:
I thought that the data-binding is possibly adding some internal `$...` fields to `entity` but these are hopefully disregarded (at least this is the case in `angular.equals` so they should probably be disregarded in the `$watch` too, I assume).

Comment: Every watcher is called once to initialize.

Comment: @zeroflagL: I'm only setting up the `$watch` once.

Answer (score 1):

`$watch` with object equality flag `true` compares the properties of the old object copy with the current object. Therefore the listener fires when a property name is changed, added, or removed. You can try something like the following:

```
$scope.$watch("entity", function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if(Object.keys(newVal).length !== Object.keys(oldVal).length)
        return; //Detect added properties

    if ($scope.entity.Id) {
            $scope.validate();
    }
}, true
```

Comment: The main question is still: why should data-binding add, change or remove properties?

Comment: Two possibilities, either $scope.entity.someBoundData is not initialized, so binding adds the someBoundData property to $scope.entity, or it is not initialized with the correct value, such as the empty string "" and is therefore updated on binding